# Slider Responsiveness

Tags: css

My web theme has a slider built in that wasn't full width.  I did some research and to make it full width I added a 1400px wide image and set the containers css to:

```
width: 100%;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
```

However it doesn't scale to smaller screen sizes like I was hoping.  I did some research but can't find anything that works or is that specific.  How do you think I can fix this and make it look the same on all screens.

Comment: The container has relative width but its child element don't.

Comment: Yes!  I get it now. I set the image to also 100% width and it works well now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `width` set `max-width`

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
div {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: auto;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="//placehold.it/1400x900" />
</div>
```

Comment: I think I understand the principals but I can't get it to work in practice.  It doesn't seem to have any affect and makes it go back to normal size.  Can you tell me what specific elements to choose if I give you the url?  The site I'm making is www.timberspirit.com